# Numpy unit tests errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, ubuntu, numpy

I have two unit test errors in numpy which i can't seem to decipher:
I'm running Ubuntu 16.4

```
> Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.11.0
NumPy relaxed strides checking option: False
NumPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
nose version 1.3.
```

and then the errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in        loadTestsFromName
addr.filename, addr.module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/tests/test_indexing.py", line 17, in <module>
cdll = np.ctypeslib.load_library('multiarray', np.core.multiarray.__file__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 163, in load_library
raise OSError("no file with expected extension")
OSError: no file with expected extension
```

======================================================================

### ERROR: Failure: OSError (no file with expected extension)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
addr.filename, addr.module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/tests/test_ctypeslib.py", line 11, in <module>
cdll = load_library('multiarray', np.core.multiarray.__file__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 163, in load_library
raise OSError("no file with expected extension")
OSError: no file with expected extension
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Source code for some hints of what it is trying to do: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/ctypeslib.py, just search for your error.

Comment: Looks like it's got to do with how Ubuntu installs numpy - there is a multiarray so file but it's named slightly different from the filenames that are tried

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error happening for numpy 1.11.0 and Ubuntu 16.04. I upgraded numpy to the most recent one `[sudo] pip install --upgrade numpy`, and then the tests worked.